# Confusion matrix with logarithmic colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created a confusion matrix with a colorbar using Tikz. But the problem is that some classes have far more samples than others and thus I think it would be more representative to have logarithmic scale on the colorbar. How can I do this with tikz and pgfplots?

[image: Confusion matrix]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3, Class 4},
            xtick={0,...,3},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3, Class 4},
            ytick={0,...,3},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=90
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=4,
            point meta=explicit,draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            0 0 0
            1 0 630
            2 0 8
            3 0 4
            
            0 1 0
            1 1 0
            2 1 1
            3 1 79
            
            0 2 0
            1 2 0
            2 2 1
            3 2 0
            
            0 3 0
            1 3 0
            2 3 0
            3 3 83
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I do want the numbers on the confusion matrix to stay intact, I just want the colors itself to be on a logarithmic scale. I do understand that there will be a problem with 0, but that can maybe be fixed as a special case in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution with the help of someone over at freenode. This can be solved by calculating a logarithmic meta and then displaying the raw values instead of the transformed meta values. The problem with 0 is solved by adding 1.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3, Class 4},
            xtick={0,...,3},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={Class 1, Class 2, Class 3, Class 4},
            ytick={0,...,3},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=90
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\Cvalue},
            visualization depends on={\thisrow{C} \as \Cvalue},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=4,
            point meta={log10(\thisrow{C}+1)},
            draw=gray
        ] table {
            x y C
            0 0 0
            1 0 630
            2 0 8
            3 0 4
            
            0 1 0
            1 1 0
            2 1 1
            3 1 79
            
            0 2 0
            1 2 0
            2 2 1
            3 2 0
            
            0 3 0
            1 3 0
            2 3 0
            3 3 83
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```